# Создание хорошего описания к коду

Tags: yii, структуры, проектирование, проекты

Как возник данный вопрос, я, наверное, уже перейду к сути. Есть запрос на сервак, у него 26 параметров. (мило правда?) запросов к серваку примерно может быть около 350! в каждом от 5 до кучи передаваемых параметров.

Смысл в следующем, вот и вопрос.

У меня каждый запрос разбит на свой **Action** каждый **action** лежит в *отдельном файле*

**//upd_start**

Почему выбрано именно разбиение **actions** на файлы. Проект достаточно большой. Чтобы все разработчики не расширяли сам контроллер, а просто дописывали в него 1-2 строчки для подключения нового экшена + удобно редактировать проект такими кусками, а не целым файлом, который бы терпел изменения постоянно. По мне так это правильно.

**//upd_end**

пример:

```
public function actions()
     {
     /* All actions in this controller 
      * are located in folder 
      * application.controllers.frontend.requests
      */
     return array(
                  'gf' => 'application.controllers.frontend.requests.gf',
                   // и т.д.
                );
      }
```

Первый вопрос:

> На каком языке писать описание ко всему проекту?

В данный момент пытаюсь описывать на ENG, как может быть заметно из вышеописанной функции, описание на ENG.

В **gf.php** описание тоже на ENG

```
@NumSeats          - The total number of passengers for which availability is being requested
 @StartDt           - Date of Departure or Arrival. 
 @StartPt           - Airport or city code of the customer embarkation.
 @EndPt             - Airport or city code of the customer Destination.
 @StartTm           - Requested departure in 24-hour clock
```

В принципе, считаю что это правильно! В плане разработки проекта другими участниками, как русско, так и англо говорящими.

Но есть одно но. Есть люди в компании не особо понимающие ENG язык и тем самым просят комментировать код на русском языке.

В чем прикол? Ну на русском читать ведь проще! Соглашусь, переводить технический ENG это пипец как "весело", схожу потихонечку с ума + ко всему не всегда получается правильно перевести ENG на RUS в связи с разными обстоятельствами (незнание каких-то оборотов и т.д.) В общем хватает веселых вещей по языкам.

Есть варианты решения, забить на ENG писать только на RUS второе решение писать только на ENG, третье писать в 2х вариантах и в ENG/RUS что решит траблы обоих случаев, но увеличит кол-во описания к коду, что на мой взгляд не есть хорошо.

Вот на стадии проектирования проекта и хочу выяснить как лучше делать.
С одной стороны хочется доставить всем удовольствие от разработки и писать описание для всех, все равно приходится переводить мануал системы на RUS, с другой стороны писать описалово на 2х языках муторно и как-то по кол-ву кода в файле слишком много.

Будет ли большое описание влиять на производительность кода?

последнее редактирование - 11.06.2013 15:32
Будут дополнения озвучу, пока все.

Жду ваших интересных отзывов по теме.

Естественно буду продолжать открывать новые вопросы по теме разработки.

Answer (score 4):

[@Shrek](/users/4597/shrek), не очень понял, что это за люди, которые хотят на русском.

Если они будут сопровождать проект, то лучше делать комментарии на RUS.

Если же это кто-то просто из любопытных заказчиков, то как Вам удобней (видимо, оставьте ENG).

А писать **комментарии** в 2-х вариантах, это ни к чему. Тогда уж лучше их вообще не писать, т.к. через полгода один из вариантов точно уже не будет соответствовать коду.

Comment: @avp я вот хотел писать на ENG ибо ближе к разработчикам, я бы так назвал.

Это не любопытный заказчик, это начальник, который в данный момент начинает разбираться в Yii и хочет RUS комментс :)

Да и на ENG смотрится лучше, да и как-то ближе к сердцу.

В 2х вариантах через пол года они будут соответствовать, т.к. XML сервера не притерпит изменений. В худшем случае добавится 1 параметр.

Comment: @Shrek, если в разработке вас только 2 человека - Вы и начальник, а проект в перспективе только локальный, то может лучше делать на RUS.

А если какие-то термины плохо переводятся, то оставляйте их на ENG. Многие этого не любят, а по мне, так нормально. В комментариях главное что бы понятно было. Поэтому если нет устоявшегося перевода термина - лучше оставить родное (или слэнговое) слово.

И еще, вряд ли Вы сами будете всегда сопровождать эти программы, а новым людям по русски м.б. проще.

Comment: Да вот я и думаю, кто дальше будет курировать прожект.
Да, наверное будет правильнее на RUS и оставлять ENG в труднодоступных местах :)